# What are some verses from Hindu scriptures which are against men?

Tags: men

I want to know some antimen verses from Hindu scriptures.

Comment: Why do you want to know these? Can you add some context?

Comment: @sv, because *woke* people find it trendy to ask what is against women in scriptures, cherry pick those, popularize and then ridicule. These mahanubhavas are unaware of the fact that scriptures are for the upliftment of atma (soul) which has no gender.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! Currently your question looks unclear and needs more clarity, please add related context i.e. specify the "when".

Comment: @ram and sv. I think we have a close vote type "Needs details or clarity". We may use that type to cast close vote on these type of question.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto, i don't want to close this question. I want it to be open to counter those 'scriptures are against women' type questions.

Comment: A good question. Deserves more research and detailed response.

Comment: Even without taking the answer to be exhaustive, it seems the counter-theory implied in comments has been given enough rope XD

Answer (score 6):

I am not completely sure but below is a verse that might be thought of as against men. A man is a danger to a woman.

> Just as a woman is a danger to a man desiring progress on the
> spiritual path, **so is a man to woman.**

Srimad Bhagavata Purana III.31.41